# Smoothing edges in Figma

Tags: vector, figma

How do I make the edges of the shape completely smooth (straight) as opposed to what I have now after having converted a `.png` image into the vector shape.

[image]

Comment: What does the the original PNG look like?  How did you trace it?  Did you use a plugin? If so, what settings?

Comment: The original PNG looks rough like that. I converted PNG to SVG with online converter.

Comment: Online vector tracing is often not very good.  Try Inkscape (which is free). It has a Trace Bitmap function which allows smoothing to be controlled. [see example here](https://imgur.com/R0XnlMZ). You can then save as SVG and import into Figma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Image Tracer plugin in Figma. It'll (probably) fix the edges. But for an exact solution, you have to draw it as a vector with pen tool in Figma.